# How do I compute this integration? (the characteristic function of Levy distribution)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Define

$$f(x) :=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{-1/2x}}{x^{3/2}}, & \text{for $x>0$} \\[4ex] 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Then, how do I prove that $$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx}f(x) dx = e^{-\sqrt{-2it}}$$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$?

Since $f$ does not have a moment generating function, we cannot apply analytic continuation technique here to prove the above equality. Hence, I think we must directly prove this; but how?

Comment: Just a suggestion: You might want to make that first equation larger with "\displaystyle".  I had trouble reading the 3/2 exponent.  Now, let me see if I can figure this out ....

Comment: @bob.sacamento How do I adjust the font size..?

Comment: seems to be aduplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566188/the-characteristic-function-of-levy-distribution

Comment: @MikeHawk The answer in that post must be justified. The step using the change of variable is informal, since it is complex-valued.

Comment: @MikeHawk See for instance this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2949892/44669